# Connection to an existing wi-fi signal

Tags: c++, qt, networking, wifi

I have an application that looks and shows all possible wifi connections around me. After it finds them I can choose one. I want user to enter password for chosen wi-fi connection.

```
void availabelNetworks::on_connect_clicked()
{
QNetworkConfigurationManager mng;
QNetworkConfiguration cfg;
mng.updateConfigurations();
auto nc = mng.allConfigurations();
for(auto &x: nc)
{
    if(x.bearerType()==QNetworkConfiguration::BearerWLAN)
    {
        if(x.name()==ui->listWidget->currentItem()->text())
        {
            cfg=x;
        }
    }
}
auto session = new QNetworkSession(cfg, this);
if(cfg.state()==QNetworkConfiguration::Undefined)
{
    //I want user to enter password here
}
else
{
    session->open();
}


}
```

Is there any way I can do it in QT?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Do you want the user to enter the wifi network's password or a password specified by you somewhere in the program?

Comment: @tambre, Wifi network's password.

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick:

```
QString pwd = QInputDialog::getText(
              ui->listWidget->currentItem()->text(), 
              "Insert your password", 
              QLineEdit::Password);
```

The important thing is the last argument of `getText` : `QLineEdit::Password` [here are the options](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#EchoMode-enum)